# SQL SERVER, importing from CSV file. Data conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to import data from a CSV file into a table.
I am presented by this error:

> "Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data
>   conversion for column "dstSupport" returned status value 2 and status
>   text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of
>   data."."

However, I do not even need to convert this column, as you see in the image below:

[image]

The column is of type bit, and I used DST_BOOL.

Comment: If its a string type make sure the destination length is big enough.

Comment: it is bit type and I assigned it to DST_BOOL

Comment: I will  include that

Comment: If the .csv has a header, then make sure you use the 'top row as header' option.

Comment: do you have nulls in csv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being a parsing error. I had a string with commas within it, and these strings within the commas were being placed in my bit column. I fixed it by changing the delimiter from a comma to a pipe